# Java ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream()) catches null object

Tags: java, sockets, object, stream, server

I'm making a client server couple. My client connects to server very well and it creates ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream()) over the socket, from server to client and vice versa. Then for some mystical reason my ObjectInputStream of the server somehow catches a null object. Client haven't sent anything over the socket (I did put /*..*/ over the object send method to make this sure and even System.out.printed all the objects sent earlier) Server catches that mystical object only once, and after that all the objects sent By client work just as they should..

```
class ClientThread extends Thread {
        //The socket where to listen/talk
        Socket socket;
        ObjectInputStream sInput;
        ObjectOutputStream sOutput;
        InputStream fInput;
        OutputStream Output;
        //my unique id (easier for deconnection)
        int id;
        //Objects that we will be receiving
        Incomingdata datain;
        //the date we connect
        String date;
        Player player;
        boolean Connected = false;

        //Constructor
        ClientThread(Socket socket){
            id = uniqueId++;
            this.socket = socket;
            try{
                sOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                sInput = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                Output = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println("Couldn't create Input/Output streams");
            }
            date = new Date().toString();
        }

        // what will run forever
        public void run() {
            // to loop until LOGOUT
            Connected = true;
            while(Connected) {
                try {
                    datain = (Incomingdata) sInput.readObject(); //<--- this catches the mystical null! Even if nothing is sent over the socket?
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    TextArea.AddLine("Exception reading Streams: " + e);
                    break;              
                }
                catch(ClassNotFoundException e2) {
                    break;
                }
```

Comment: As I was explaining to someone the other day, Object & Data Input/Output streams are technology from a bygone era, where issues like big-endian vs little-endian still existed, and there weren't good communication standards. We now have XML and JSON - They are both a much better solution than using Object streams

Comment: I think that's not actually an answer to my question?

Comment: Seems like the problem has disappeared as weirdly as it appeared!

Comment: @ControlAltDel You mustn't go around claiming that XML and JSON have made binary protocols obsolete. They haven't, and they can't.

Comment: @ControlAltDel - indeed, the (rhetorical) counter-argument is that binary protocols like Protobuf have made XML and JSON obsolete.  The reality is that binary and text based protocols BOTH have a place, and NEITHER of them obsolete the other.

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'null object'. Define 'catches a null object'. Do you mean (1) *returns* a null, or (2) *throws* a `NullPointerException`?

Answer (score 0):

You can only receive a null if you send a null.

(There is a widespread misconception that `readObject()` returns null at end of stream. It doesn't.)